# The new Router Component for Angular2 does not seem to have provision for templateUrl .

Tags: angular, angular-routing

The new Router Component for Angular2 does not seem to have provision for templateUrl . Is there a way to navigate to a page as it was done using $stateProviders while providing a templateUrl?
Also there seems to be no support for resolve. What would be the best way to get data from a rest call before invoking the controller/component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no support for templateUrl in the router

You can use guards (`CanActivate` see also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) that return a future
or just wrap your template with `*ngIf="data"`

Comment: So if i  need to redirect to different html page, it wont be possible ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I don't know $stateProviders. In Angular2 every HTML has to be in a component. Just navigate to a route with a different compinent.

Comment: Okay. All I meant to say was that if templateUrl was not an option while using the ng2 component router then how to inject html files separately for different views. But I think it can be done in the component itself. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you want different HTML you route to a different component.